# Changing syntax highlight rules priority

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want Vim to highlight tags (`#tag`) in my Markdown files.

I extended the default highlighting by creating `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` with the following content:

```
syn match mdTag '#\w\+'
hi link mdTag htmlTagName
```

This works as expected: tags are now highlighted as the `htmlTagName` style specifies. However, if the link appears in the end of a title, it is just highlighted as the title and not as a tag.

So `Foo bar #tag` works well, but `# Chapter 2 #tag` does not.

Is there a way to give the tag highlight rule a higher priority over the heading highlight rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [default syntax rules for Markdown bundled with Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/syntax/markdown.vim), the reason why your `mdTag` rule is not matching inside a heading is that the existing heading rules (`markdownH1`, `markdownH2`, etc.) use a `contains=` attribute to specify which other rules can match inside the headings.

It turns out all those heading rules include a cluster `@markdownInline` in their `contains=`, which makes it easy to extend the list, since you can add to an existing cluster. You can add your `mdTag` to the list with:

```
syntax cluster markdownInline add=mdTag
```

Comment: You can also overrule the contains (effectively adding to it) with containedin